# Is it proper to seperate the backend and front end of a node js project with respective package json files?

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, deployment, package.json

I built a node project with an angular front end and express backend. The angular project is in a subfolder of the node project, and as a result there are two package json files, one in the angular project and one in the node project. Now I am coming across issues when trying to deploy this full stack application to heroku, as it references my node package json but has no idea the angular project exists.

Looking at heroku angular deployment tutorials, they all dont have a node folder, rather they build their entire application in an angular project and just add a server file inside it. Thus they only work with one package.json file. I was wondering which way is proper? And if seperating is ok, is there a tutorial or guide to deploying to heroku while juggling multiple package.json files?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is basically how workspaces work.

[NPM Workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces)

The easiest way to do this is to keep your related commands in their respective folders (`"start": "ng serve"` should be in your client package.json, `"start": "node main.js"` should be in your server package.json), and when you"re in the root folder of your directory, simply run `npm start -w [client|api]`.

Hence, to deploy on heroku, simply run `npm run deploy -w client`, and it should deploy your angular application to Heroku (assuming you have wrote the deploy script for it, of course)